# How to do an EntityQuery on a custom User field?

Tags: 8

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use the EntityQuery on custom field values. As an example I have a custom field under the User bundle that stores the country in which the user lives. There are three options: US, Canada and Mexico. I'd like to use the EntityQuery to directly query the 'field_country' to get a count of how many live in one country and get their uids. Here is an export from the database for this field:

[image]

The closest I've gotten is the code snippet below. This however is not working and I'm not sure where to go from here.

```
$results = \Drupal::entityQuery('user')
      ->condition('field_country', 'Canada')
      ->execute();
```

Does anybody know? Does the entityquery give me the ability to look specific columns in a field? Thanks!

P.S. I know I could do this with a database query but I'd prefer to do it the Drupal way.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be missing a line:

```
$ids = \Drupal::entityQuery('user')
  ->condition('field_country', 'Canada')
  ->execute(); // This returns the user ids

// Load the users
$users = User::loadMultiple($ids);
foreach ($users as $uid => $user) {
    // $user contains the $user entity
}
```

More examples are located [on the docs page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityQuery/8.2.x).